# cursor falling behind the text on CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am using CodeMirror on my website, and encounter the following problem: Whenever i write anything into the code editor, the insertion point cursor (the blinking line) stays behind the text and acts very strange.

See the recorded behavior on a [youtube video](http://youtu.be/qiQ7lDbuP4Q) as it is quite hard to explain exactly what is wrong.

As a result, highlighting text and writing code is very hard since you don't know where you are in the text.

Comment: nice video :) is this only happening on the PHP mode?

Comment: @EliranMalka no, i tried javascript and html mode too.

Comment: That sometimes happens in jsFiddle too, which uses CodeMirror.